# What is needed to access a file in Google Drive using a Service Account and impersonate?

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-nodejs-client

With a Google Suite Business plan, I need to get a file from some user and copy it to Team Drive folder owned by **ANOTHER** user through a Service Account properlly authorized by Domain-Wide-Delegation.

My approach: considering that Service Account has the power to access users data, change the permission of the user's file to allow the whole domain to read it, copy it to a folder inside the Team Drive owned by *another* user and then setting the owner of Team Drive as the owner of the copied file.

The following code is always returning **File not found** for the first Google Drive request (change the permission). I guarantee that the file really exists in user's folder.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const google = require('googleapis');

fs.readFile('/path/to/my/service/account/credentials', (readError, serviceAccountData) => {

    /**
        serviceAccountData is an object:
        {
            "type": "service_account",
            "project_id": "__",
            "private_key_id": "__",
            "private_key": "__",
            "client_email": "__@__.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
            "client_id": "__",
            "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
            "token_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
            "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
            "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/___.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
        }
     */

    if (readError) {

        console.log(readError);

    } else {

        let serviceAccount = null;

        try {

            serviceAccount = JSON.parse(serviceAccountData);

        } catch (parseError) {

            console.log(parseError);

            return;

        }

        const jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT(serviceAccount.client_email, null, serviceAccount.private_key, SCOPES, null, 'lordshark@example.com');

        jwtClient.authorize((authorizeError, tokens) => {

            if (authorizeError) {

                console.log(authorizeError);

            } else {

                // ID of any file that belongs to lordshark@example.com
                // This file is stored in lordshark@example.com Google Drive (user space)
                let sourceFileId = '____';

                // ID of a folder in a Team Drive OWNED BY A DIFFERENT user that isn't lordshark@example.com
                // lordshark@example.com DOES NOT HAVE access to this Team Drive
                let teamDriveFolderId = '____'/

                const googleDrive = google.drive({
                    version: 'v3',
                    auth: jwtClient
                });

                googleDrive.permissions.create({
                    fileId: sourceFileId,
                    useDomainAdminAccess: true,
                    resource: {
                        role: 'reader',
                        type: 'domain',
                        domain: 'example.com',
                    }
                }, (createPermissionError, permissionResponse) => {

                    if (createPermissionError) {

                        console.log(createPermissionError);

                    } else {

                        googleDrive.files.copy({
                            fileId: sourceFileId,
                            supportsTeamDrives: true,
                            ignoreDefaultVisibility: true,
                            resource: {
                                description: 'Copy of a file from user to store in Team Driver',
                                parents: [teamDriveFolderId]
                            }
                        }, (copyError, copyResponse) => {

                            if (copyError) {

                                console.log(copyError);

                            } else {

                                googleDrive.permissions.create({
                                    fileId: copyResponse.id,
                                    transferOwnership: true,
                                    resource: {
                                        role: 'owner',
                                        type: 'user',
                                        emailAddress: administrator
                                    }
                                }, (ownerPermissionError, ownerPermissionResponse) => {

                                    if (ownerPermissionError) {

                                        console.log(ownerPermissionError);

                                    } else {

                                        console.log(ownerPermissionResponse);

                                    }

                                });


                            }

                        });

                    }

                });

            }

        });

    }

});
```

The stacktrace:

> { Error: File not found: 1K-dQt5uwfUc331uKc2vxUn3MP3nohLPZ.
>       at Request._callback (node_modules\googleapis\node_modules\google-auth-library\lib\transporters.js:85:15)
>       at Request.self.callback (node_modules\request\request.js:186:22)
>       at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
>       at Request.emit (events.js:191:7)
>       at Request. (node_modules\request\request.js:1163:10)
>       at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
>       at Request.emit (events.js:188:7)
>       at IncomingMessage. (node_modules\request\request.js:1085:12)
>       at IncomingMessage.g (events.js:292:16)
>       at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
>     code: 404,
>     errors:
>      [ { domain: 'global',
>          reason: 'notFound',
>          message: 'File not found: 1K-dQt5uwfUc331uKc2vxUn3MP3nohLPZ.',
>          locationType: 'parameter',
>          location: 'fileId' } ] }

Comment: I already tried with and without `lordshark@example.com`, `useDomainAdminAccess: true` and the error keeps the same.

Comment: Refactor that code, it is completely unreadable. I lost myself in the third if-else.

Comment: Sorry, Ivan. First I write 'sausage-fast-codes' for a proof of concept to understand these Google API's. I try to handle all possibles... so the amount of if's and try's instead of creating many functions. It's the callback-hell of JS. It will take me time to rewrite... but I'll make an effort.

Comment: Can you give the Drive API [files.list try-it](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/list#try-it) a try if you're able to get a positive result?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, noogui. I really tried this but no success. Always returning empty results... `{ kind: 'drive#fileList', incompleteSearch: false, files: [] }` and I tried many different queries.

Comment: I also tried with OAuth2 credentials, generating tokens and so on... and in this case I got success listing files. But only for the user with the authorization consent.

Comment: https://github.com/google/google-auth-library-nodejs/blob/b6db93a5c5d66154914e86a01539b6cacdfb9a45/src/auth/jwtclient.ts#L59

Do you have the same parameters? I think the null after scopes is wrong.

Comment: @lordshark were you able to find a solution? I am able to list files, etc... from a service account but am running into an authorization probelm when trying to update permissions on a team drive, with and without the useAdminstratorAccess.

Comment: Sorry @FantasticSponge. I did not find a solution. I stopped this project and decided to go into another way. Maybe in the future I'll need this scenario again...